# Debugging two VSCode extensions at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two VSCode extensions, extension A and extension B.
They are implemented so that extension A and extension B would communicate with each other using the exports returned by extension A's `activate()` function.

In order to test this communication, I would build one extension as a vsix, install it in VSCode, and debug the other extension. But ideally, I would prefer not to build and install one of the extensions.

Is it possible to debug the two extensions at the same time? It would be great if I could have both extensions opened in VSCode (multiroot workspace), and be able to run both extensions in the same [Extension Development Host] window.

Answer (score 0):

I swear to god I just read about this like an hour ago...

First of all, it's possible to install a [extension from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_command-line-extension-management). But you would have to call the CLI through the code somehow...

Aha! [Found it](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#custom-setup-with-vscodetest)!

```js
const cp = require('child_process');
const { downloadAndUnzipVSCode, resolveCliPathFromExecutablePath } = require('vscode-test');
const vscodeExecutablePath = await downloadAndUnzipVSCode('1.34.0');
const cliPath = resolveCliPathFromExecutablePath(vscodeExecutablePath);

// Use cp.spawn / cp.exec for custom setup
cp.spawnSync(cliPath, ['--install-other-extension', '<EXTENSION-ID-OR-PATH-TO-VSIX>'], {
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  stdio: 'inherit'
});

// Run the extension test
await runTests({
  // Use the specified `code` executable
  vscodeExecutablePath,
  extensionPath,
  testRunnerPath
});
```